# How to cache a function that takes a database connection as an input using streamlit

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, streamlit

I have a database connection:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine('my_info')
connection = engine.connect()
```

Subsequently I have a function:

```
import pandas as pd

def load_data(connection):
    sql = 'select * from tablename'
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, con = connection)
    return df
```

This is part of an app in Streamlit that I'm working on, I need streamlit to cache the output of my `load_data` function. I thought it worked like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

@st.cache()
def load_data(connection):
    sql = 'select * from tablename'
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, con = connection)
    return df
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
UnhashableTypeError: Cannot hash object of type builtins.weakref, found in the arguments of load_data().
```

The error is much longer, and if it helps I will post it. The error also contains [a link to the streamlit documentation](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/caching#the-hash_funcs-parameter). I read it and reformulated my code to look like this:

```
@st.cache()
def DBConnection():
    engine = sa.create_engine("my_info")
    conn = engine.connect()
    return conn
conn = DBConnection()

@st.cache(hash_funcs={DBConnection: id})
def load_data(connection):
        sql = 'select * from tablename'
        df = pd.read_sql(sql, con = connection)
        return df
```

But this gives me a `NameError`:

```
NameError: name 'DBConnection' is not defined
```

I've run out of idea's to try, any help would be highly appreciated. It is very possible that I misunderstood the documentation as it assumes a lot of prior knowledge about the process of hashing and caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the two methods and use:

```
@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=true)
```

Code:

```
@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=true)
def load_data():
    engine = sa.create_engine("my_info")
    conn = engine.connect()
    sql = 'select * from tablename'
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, con = conn )
    return df
```

For more you can read in [documentation](http://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/caching#advanced-caching)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried adding @st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True) to my database connection function, but this did not solve my problem. I tried adding it to the load_data function, with and without the hash_funcs parameter as specified above. But I get exactly the same error :/

Comment: @XiB i edited the answer does this work for you?

Comment: Thank you! That works!, Due to the nature of my script (there are many load_data functions) this might result in a database connection being opened and closed many times (10-15 times) the script will be run about twice per day, so max 30 connections opening and closing per day due to this one tool. I'm no expert when it comes to databases, so I have no idea how big of a problem that is to be honest).

Comment: @XiB It's not the most efficient but if it's only 30 connections a day i belive it won't be a problem. Also if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I will mark your answer as accepted, Thank you for your input!

Comment: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/performance/st.cache
st.cache was deprecated in version 1.18.0. Use st.cache_data or st.cache_resource instead.

Answer (score 0):

what i am doing is using session state - i was unable to cach any SQL query with streamlit decorators - see this [link](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/session-state#initialization)

For your case what you can do is this:

```
def load_data(connection):
    sql = 'select * from tablename'
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, con = connection)
    return df

if 'df' not in st.session_state:  # if df not in session state
    df=load_data(connection)      # get the df 
    st.session_state['df']=df     # write it to session state 
else:
    df=st.session_state['df']     # otherwise get it from session state
```